# How do I create a list with definitions using javascript and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am familiar with HTML5 & CSS3, and just starting to learn JS. I need help creating a list of string variables, and attach definitions to all of them.

Basically, I need a two column table, where the left column is the list of strings, and when you click the words, it pulls up the definition on the right. I also need to make sure that the page doesn't reload when you click on the different words.

The photo (link below) best illustrates what I'm trying to create.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/amJ1v.png

Comment: create an object hashmap. It's a long way between your image and information given in the question so question is really far too broad

Comment: Seems like a tabbed-content plugin would be an easy solution to this. If you're using a front-end framework they generally have those built in

Answer (score 2):

Well I think I got what you want, it took me a while. The only thing you have to do now is to edit the values in the array to display other text. (Delta is set).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = {
    'Alfa': 'Alfa Text',
    'Bravo': 'Bravo Text',
    'Charlie': 'Charlie Text',
    'Delta': 'Delta is the fourth letter of the Greek alphabet.<br/><br/>In the system of Greek numerals it has a value of 4.',
    'Echo': 'Echo Text',
    'Foxtrot': 'Foxtrot Text',
    'Golf': 'Golf Text',
    'Hotel': 'Hotel Text',
    'India': 'India Text',
    'Juliet': 'Juliet Text',
    'Kilo': 'Kilo Text',
    'Lima': 'Lima Text',
    'Mike': 'Mike Text',
    'November': 'November Text',
    'Oscar': 'Oscar Text',
    'Papa': 'Papa Text',
    'Quebec': 'Quebec Text',
    'Romeo': 'Romeo Text',
    'Sierra': 'Sierra Text',
    'Tango': 'Tango Text',
    'Uniform': 'Uniform Text',
    'Victor': 'Victor Text',
    'Whiskey': 'Whiskey Text',
    'X-ray': 'X-ray Text',
    'Yankee': 'Yankee Text',
    'Zulu': 'Zulu Text'
  };
  $.each(list, function(index, value) {
    var listitem = $('<li></li>');
    $('.letterlist').append(listitem.text(index));
  });
  $('.letterlist li').on('click', function() {
    //Remove class from previous item
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    //Add class to current item
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var block = $('.block.right');
    var descr = $('<p></p>');
    var value = $(this).text();
    //Empty header and content
    block.children('h1').empty();
    block.children('.content').empty();
    //Add header and content
    block.children('h1').text(value);
    block.children('.content').append(descr.html(list[value]));
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.letterlist,
.letterlist li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.letterlist li.selected {
  color: #f00;
  background: #fac6c7;
}
.letterlist li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.left {
  font-size: 28px;
}
.content {
  background: #fac6c7;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 20px 20px;
  padding: 16px 12px;
}
h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block left">
  <ul class="letterlist"></ul>
</div>
<div class="block right">
  <h1></h1>
  <div class="content">Select an item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can implement this, but if you'd like to specifically generate everything from data using JavaScript (if you've gotten the data from an AJAX request to some API, for instance), then you can obtain/create an object with the key-value pairs matching up to words and their definitions respectively:

```
var dictionary = {
    first: '<h2>First</h2> Is the 1st definition.',
    second: '<h2>Second</h2> Is the 2nd definition.',
    third: '<h2>Third</h2> Is the 3rd definition.'
};
```

Let's say you have some appropriately styled markup to start off with as a shell, which consists of two panels - one which will contain an unordered list of words, and another which will contain the definition text:

```
<div id="words" class="panel">
  <ul></ul>
</div>

<div id="definition" class="panel"></div>
```

From here, you can iterate through each of the pairs in the `dictionary` object, where you then create HTML elements, assign click handlers, and append the elements to the DOM for each:

```
// For each of the word/definition pairs....
$.each(dictionary, function(word, definition) {
    // Create a list item to hold the word
    var listItem = $('<li>').addClass('word').text(word);

    // Give the word item a click handler to display it's definition when clicked
    listItem.click(function() {
        // Set the definition HTML to the current word's definition
        $('#definition').html(definition);
    });

    // Append it to the list of words in the DOM
    $('#words ul').append(listItem);
});
```

Notice that the click handler is capturing the `definition` in context within the current iteration of the dictionary.

Here's a full, but minimal, example implementation of this method using jQuery with some explanatory comments:

```js
$(function() {
 // Define a dictionary of words, perhaps fetched from an API
    var dictionary = {
        first: '<h2>First</h2> Is the 1st definition.',
        second: '<h2>Second</h2> Is the 2nd definition.',
        third: '<h2>Third</h2> Is the 3rd definition.'
    };
    
    // For each of the word/definition pairs....
    $.each(dictionary, function(word, definition) {
        // Create a list item to hold the word
        var listItem = $('<li>').addClass('word').text(word);
        
        // Give the word item a click handler to display it's definition when clicked
        listItem.click(function() {
            // Set the definition HTML to the current word's definition
            $('#definition').html(definition);
            
            // Add the highlight class to the current element only
            $('#words li').removeClass('highlight');
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        });
        
        // Append it to the list of words in the DOM
        $('#words ul').append(listItem);
    });
});
```

```css
.panel {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 250px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.word.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.word {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="words" class="panel">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<div id="definition" class="panel"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Keep your concerns separate. This means you keep your templates in HTML, your styles in CSS and your application logic in JS.

**JS**

```
var definitions = {
  alpha: 'Alpha definition',
  beta: 'Beta definition'
};

var $definitionsList = $('ul#definition-list');
var $definitions = $(document.createDocumentFragment());

for (var key in definitions) {
  $('<li/>')
    .text(key)
    .on('click', displayDefinition.bind(null, key, definitions[key]))
    .appendTo($definitions);
}

$definitionsList.append($definitions);

function displayDefinition(name, definition) {
  $('#definition-display h1').text(name);
  $('#definition-display p').text(definition);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <ul id="definition-list"></ul>
  <div id="definition-display">
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#definition-list {
  // Some cool styles for the list
}

#definition-list li {
  // Some cool styles for the list items
}
```